# Extract all string in a files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

These are the content of a file :-

```
org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Process Started MessageID=1AMULE
One
Two
Three
org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Process Completd MessageID=1AMULE
org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Process Started MessageID=2BMULE
org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Process Completd MessageID=2BMULE
```

Here I want to extract the strings `1A,1B` i.e after `org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Process Started MessageID=` and before `MULE` in python.

Comment: What did you try? Please include all relevant code. What is your question?

Comment: Please post your attempt, this is not a free code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.split` on `"="`

**Ex:**

```
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if "=" in line:
            print(line.split("=")[1].strip())
```

**Output:**

```
1AMULE
1AMULE
2BMULE
2BMULE
```